# Multiple shell parameter assignments prefixing a bash command

Tags: bash, command-line, environment-variables

In the [bash manual section 3.7.4](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Environment), it states

> The environment for any simple command or function may be augmented
>   temporarily by prefixing it with parameter assignments, as described
>   in [Shell Parameters [section 3.4]](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters).

And a trivial example of this is

```
MYVAR=MYVALUE mycommand
```

I have read section 3.4 and I still can't figure out how to specify multiple parameter assignments. Note that the statement in 3.7.4 is definitely plural, implying that it is possible.

The following does not seem to work:

```
MYVAR1=abc MYVAR2=xyz mycommand
```

I am using bash version 4.1, 23 December 2009.

Comment: Works here. You're screwing something else up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, my example was over-simplified. This works fine:

```
mycommand () { echo MYVAR1=[$MYVAR1]; echo MYVAR2=[$MYVAR2]; }
MYVAR1=abc MYVAR2=xyz mycommand
```

but this does not:

```
mycommand () { echo MYVAR1=[$MYVAR1]; echo MYVAR2=[$MYVAR2]; }
MYVAR1=abc MYVAR2=xyz for f in ~/*.txt; do mycommand; done
```

and the key difference is this phrase:

> for any simple command or function

A `for` command is a complex command, not "a simple command or function", according to [section 3.2](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Commands).

Comment: But this does: `for f in ~/*.txt ; do MYVAR1=abc MYVAR2=xyz mycommand; done`

Answer (score 2):

It should work. That is acceptable syntax.  Here's an example:

```
$ cat a
#!/bin/sh
echo $MYVAR1
echo $MYVAR2
$ ./a


$ MYVAR1=abc MYVAR2=xyz ./a
abc
xyz
$
```

UPDATE: Your updated example given in your answer will work if you precede the simple command with the variables as required:

```
mycommand () { echo MYVAR1=[$MYVAR1]; echo MYVAR2=[$MYVAR2]; }
for f in ~/*.txt ; do MYVAR1=abc MYVAR2=xyz mycommand; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that method used.

You could always just pass in regular parameters to the script.

Updating for new example:

This works in both situations:

```
> mycommand () { echo MYVAR1=[$1]; echo MYVAR2=[$2]; }

> mycommand a b
MYVAR1=[a]
MYVAR2=[b]

> for f in ~/file*.txt; do mycommand a b; done
MYVAR1=[a]
MYVAR2=[b]
MYVAR1=[a]
MYVAR2=[b]
```

Comment: It's perfectly legal and defined in the POSIX standard (it's not even a bashism):  'A "simple command" is a sequence of optional variable assignments and redirections, in any sequence, optionally followed by words and redirections, terminated by a control operator.'  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01

Comment: What should technically work and what is easy to make work are often two different things.  Why beat yourself up over something that you can make work another way in two shakes of a lamb's tail?

Comment: Huh?  Passing a parameter and setting a variable are not the same thing.  And this is basic shell stuff.  There's nothing tough about it.

Comment: If there wasn't anything tough about it, you wouldn't have the opportunity to answer a question on it.